# Spring Boot ignores beans from Java config class using Spring Profile

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-profiles

When I run my application on Eclipse with a classical context loading, no worries, the beans defines on the config class corresponding with the Spring Profile chosen are correctly instanciated.

```
public class BasketHandlerLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:config/spring/spring-archibald-basket-handler-context.xml");
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}
```

But, when I run the application with Spring Boot, these beans are not instanciated.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:config/spring/spring-archibald-basket-handler-context.xml")
public class BasketHandlerLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(BasketHandlerLoader.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is the java configuration class for the "dev" Spring profile:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource("classpath:filters/dev.properties") })
public class DevPersistenceConfig extends AbstractPersistenceConfig {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return super.createDataSource(env);
    }

    @Override
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return super.createHibernateProperties(env);
    }
}
```

Here the *AbstractPersistenceConfig* class containing the others beans not instanciated:

```
public abstract class AbstractPersistenceConfig {

    // Constants...

    // ************************** ABSTRACT METHODS **************************

    /**
    * Returns a property list containing the Hibernate properties.
    * 
    * @return the Hibernate properties.
    */
    public abstract Properties hibernateProperties();

    /**
    * Defines the application datasource bean corresponding with the current Spring Profile.
    * 
    * @return the application datasource bean corresponding with the current Spring Profile.
    */
    @Bean
    public abstract DataSource dataSource();

    /**
    * Defines the Hibernate session factory bean.
    * 
    * @return the {@code LocalSessionFactoryBean}.
    */
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { HIBERNATE_PACKAGE_TO_SCAN });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
    * Defines the bean allowing to Hibernate to support the transaction handling mechanism.
    * 
    * @return the {@code HibernateTransactionManager}.
    */
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }

    // ************************** PROTECTED METHODS **************************

    // ...

    // ************************** PRIVATE METHODS **************************

    // ...
}
```

I tried to run the application with the following commands with the same result:

```
java -jar archibald-basket-handler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev

java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev archibald-basket-handler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Concretely, the bean "*sessionFactory*" is not instanciated and cannot be injected into my *GenericDaoImpl* class...

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basketDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory fr.ina.archibald.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
        at fr.ina.archibald.basket.loader.BasketHandlerLoader.main(BasketHandlerLoader.java:30)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory fr.ina.archibald.dao.impl.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.     Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
        ... 23 more
```

I use the Spring Boot 1.0.2.RELEASE without the Spring Boot parent POM. I just defines this on the POM :

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you have some ideas?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run `BasketHandlerLoader` with Boot as a `main` from Eclipse with that `dev` profile ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes it's the same result on Eclipse...

Comment: It's not obvious that `DevPersistenceConfig` is ever loaded by your main method. What's the connection?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. But DevPersistenceConfig is loaded by a component-scan defined on a XML file. And it works fine when I run this app without Spring Boot on Eclipse and also when I load the same Spring context (the same XML file) on my webapp via Tomcat.

Comment: As I say on the answer below, DevPersistenceConfig is instanciated by Spring, but not the @Bean methods inside. So, 'dataSource()', 'sessionFactory()' and the others bean methods are not instanciated...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to `@Import` your `@Configuration` class directly or use the `@ComponentScan` annotation. You initial example that uses `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` will work because the XML processing happens early, and the `<component-scan>` will find your `@Configuration` classes before they are processed.

With the second example `SpringApplication` has already started processing your `@Configuration` classes and the XML is loaded via `@ImportResource`. By this time it is not possible for the XML `<component-scan>` to add more `@Configuration`.

Sort answer: Try `@ComonentScan` on your `BasketHandlerLoader` class.

Answer (score 0):

Great!!! It works!
A big big thank you Phil (for the solution and the explanations!)  :-)

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:config/spring/spring-archibald-basket-handler-context.xml")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "fr.ina.archibald.dao.config.persistence" }, includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Component.class, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION))
public class BasketHandlerLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(BasketHandlerLoader.class, args);
    }
}
```